# Not able to fire google tag manager due to Parse Errors

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get Google Tag Manager to track the amount pulled from my Product row - It keeps flagging to say it's expecting ')' or '}' and I can't test the code

```
    function() {
   function calcTotal() {
    var p = {
      qty: parseInt($(.prod-row.qty)).text().trim());
      tax: parseFloat($(.prod-row.tax)).text().trim().slice(1));
      price: parseFloat($(.prod-row.item-cost)).text().trim().slice(1));
      });
  });
   return p;
}
```

It seems right to me but not GTM any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I spot two places right away, where you opened something with just a `{`, but then the closing counterpart is `})` And you did not manage to match the amounts of `(` and `)` correctly either.

Comment: I'm really new to using Javascript - So what would you change?

Comment: Put this into any basic code editor, that has the ability to highlight the matching brackets, when you put the cursor on one of them – then you should be able to spot what is out of place rather quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm going to try see if Atom works on it

Answer (score 0):

After correcting syntax errors,

```
  function calcTotal() {
     var p = {
       qty: parseInt($('.prod-row.qty')).text().trim(),
       tax: parseFloat($('.prod-row.tax')).text().trim().slice(1),
       price: parseFloat($('.prod-row.item-cost')).text().trim().slice(1),
       }

    return p;
 }
```

Comment: You guys are amazing... I'm going to go over the tutorials though - Clearly need to get better!